# Find the exact phrase in a string (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql-server-2008

I receive the file from third party, which I upload to a table. It has a `Description` column in which I have to find an "Account NO" (9 characters in length).

A few sample descriptions:

```
FROM AMH-061060-POK UNSECURED OVER 40 DAYS
MAINTENANCE FEE A/C A4G123456
ADJUST BALANCE VS 6PK-123123
REIMBURSEMENT OF CHECK RE-ORDER FEE A4G111111 p11
Asset Mgmt acct gold annual fee MPL NFL234234.
```

`Description` column is a free text and doesn't know where the account no appears.

As you see above, it may appear at the end of the description or in the middle somewhere or at the start.

For this AMH-061060-POK, we truncate POK and remove '-' to get 9 length account number.

Any help is appreciated in finding the account number using SQL functions?

Comment: it's text, so you're limited to tsql string functions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms181984.aspx  and this is way too broad. we are not here to write a text parser for you. YOU figure out how to identify an account number in the text, we'll just (maybe) try help fix that code.

Comment: @MarcB I don't even think that this is a job for SQL Server.  Rather, he should load the text into Java or maybe C# and then use string functions, regex, etc., there to get his account number.

Comment: indeed. while I'm sure there's a jon skeet-type out there who can implement a complete AI to identify OP's text using nothing but a couple string functions and select queries with 101% reliability, but I don't think they're going to be hanging around on this site.

Comment: @Mark B, i Know the sql string functions like charindex, patindex, substring but my main road block is , i don't know the exact occurrence of the Account No. if it appears always at the end , i can use Right function. OR i can use Pattern(phrase) and use the substring function........

Comment: @Tim Are you talking about creating a sql server CLR Integration.

Comment: Since morning,i read different articles about creation of CLR Database objects and use them as functions in Sql Server.I think use of regex will solve my problem.Does anyone help me in writing regex for my Account no. it is 3 chars and 6 numbers,total 9 in length, any case???

Answer (score 0):

Anupama - in the first example, how do you know that the account number is "AMH-061060" and not "UNSECURED"? Both are nine characters.

What is logic in determining which string is the account number? First define it, then you can code it.

Comment: Account No should be a separate word with 9 or more in length. I consider first 3 alphanumeric following by 6 numbers.I am thinking to remove '-' dashes before sending to REGEX